# Generating a PDF

Tags: .net, pdf, gdi+, gdi

I am wanting to learn how to generate a PDF, I don't want to use any third party tools, I want to create it myself in code. The only things I have seen so far as examples is code I have looked at by opening up reflector on a 3rd party dll, to see what is happening. Unfortunately the dll's I have seen so far seem to be hitting user32.dll and gdi32.dll, to help creating the pdf document, my issue is I have no idea what they are doing and more importantly why ?

Does anyone have any good tutorials or references, which may point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use third party tools? The PDF specification is large and complicated, doing this by yourself can take _years_.

Comment: Is there a valid reason you don't want to use any third party tools?

Comment: @Oded - Snap!, we posted that same time

Comment: There are very few programs on Windows that have no dependency on user32.dll or gdi32.dll. The first is where most Windows APIs live. The second is where all the GDI (Graphics Device Interface) APIs live. Even on .NET, the higher level layers still translate to calls to these lower level APIs.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel.  Not a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, the reason I want to find out how it works is purely a learning exercise. I don't wish to reinvent the wheel, just learn what is actually going on, so I can produce something very very very basic.

Comment: @yodaj007 - you say that, but the wheels on most cars are quite different to the wheels on horse-drawn carriages. Sometimes, a reinvented wheel is better - either in general or for some specific application - than previously available wheels. An occasional reinvention of the wheel isn't always a bad thing, so long as you're aware that that's what you're doing, and understand that inventing a genuinely better wheel will be a pretty tough job by now.

Comment: @Steve314:  You understand what I meant.

Comment: @yodaj007 - yes, you meant that you have made assumptions about the questioner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spec is the ultimate guide.  Here is what you will ultimately have to do:

- Write a header
- Write objects that define the content
- Write a cross-reference table
- Write a trailer

The header is easy - it defines that the file is PDF and the version.
Objects data types in PDF.  This includes bool, number, string, list/array, dictionary and stream.
Objects are either written directly or indirectly.
Direct objects are written as is.
Indirect objects are written like this:

```
<objid> <generation> obj <direct object> endobj
```

For example, I could write:

```
3 0 obj (This is a string within PDF.) endobj
```

And whenever I want to use that string elsewhere, I just have to use an indirect reference, which is defined as:

```
<objid> <generation> R
```

in this case, I could refer to my string as:

```
3 0 R
```

To quickly find an object, there is a cross reference table that tells where an object of a particular id and generation lives in the file.

So, in addition to simply writing objects to the file, you *have to* keep track of the file position where indirect objects have been defined.

All of this is doable, but you're going to quickly find that as you write these files that it's going to become really challenging to make changes in your output stream and keep things neat and tidy.  What's worse, is that other people have done this too, so now there are a pile of garbage PDFs out in the wild that Acrobat manages to cope with somehow.  For example, GhostScript (hopefully this is fixed), produced PDFs whose cross-reference tables were complete garbage - they pointed at nothing useful.  Then there are producers that out and out violate the spec by using the wrong data type for dictionary entries or others that have spec-required information missing.

It's fairly nightmarish to consume PDF.

Still, it's an interesting exercise, but if you want to do anything significant, you need to start writing good tools that manage all the indirect references for you and the cross reference tables and dictionaries and type checking and so on and so forth.  In the end, you'll find that maybe an existing library would serve you better.

And being the author of tools that consume and generate PDF, I will plead that you don't let any of your non-compliant PDFs out into the wild.

Comment: Thanks in the long run, I will be going down the 3rd party route, this is purely a learning exercise, so I can put together something extremely basic.

Comment: @plinth Btw is there an *official* specs?

Comment: I know this thread is long dead, but can you point me to which controls you've had success with? Our main problem is that some PDFs cannot be stitched (PDF versions 7+), others tools cope with the later versions of Acrobat, but do not preserve form fields. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7):

We ran a set of tutorials on creating a basic PDF on our blog at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/?s=%22Make+your+own+PDF+file%22

Answer (score 2):

I know you've stated you don't want to use third party tools but please at least take a look at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).  Unless there really is a genuine reason you can't be using such a tool this should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

For PDF:

- [PDFjet Open Source Edition](http://pdfjet.com/os/edition.html)
- [Sharppdf](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/)

And [Sharppdf Tutorials](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/Tutorials.html)

Do you care not if it costs a bit, and want the best. Then I would recommend I [Aspose.Pdf. NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx)

**Edit:** I see now that you do not want to use 3d party. But I would recommend you in the strongest! This will take and are not lønomt when there is so much already. We make no wheel when it exists, does one?

But vilst you really want to spend your time on this, I made a fixed on [nfop](http://nfop.sourceforge.net/) and seen how they do it there, by reading the code.

And read on [Portable Document Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format). When to make stuff like that from from the start of is IMPORTANT to understand what standards they use and how the format is built up.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe hosts a copy of the ISO PDF Specification that is free to download.  For something like this, it will be INVALUABLE:

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There is a fine line between using a ready tool or looking at its code before writing your own. If the later is acceptable to you, just choose a nice Open Source tool, like http://www.pdfforge.org/, and look at the code.

Warning: if you plan to ever distribute your tool, taking too much inspiration from an Open Source tool may force you to make yours Open Source as well. I'm not a lawyer, I don't know how much is too much.

Comment: This is just purely a learning exercise, I have project in mind however where I will be using a 3rd party tool to generate a PDF.